# Add banner between products in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, banner, product

How can I add a banner between products on a shop page in grid mode? For example:

4 products side by side
image banner
4 products side by side
image banner

These two banners are different.

I have searched for this answer but couldn't find anything about Woocommerce. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Will it be the same banner each time or different?

Comment: Add the image files in archive-product.php

Comment: Two different banners